# Web App stops working if added to home screen on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, web

I have developed a web app using Angular + Angular Material, and my app runs well in Safari on iOS 9. But when some of our customers use "Add to Home Screen" feature to create a shortcut on their home screens, on some devices our app stops loading, without any errors. It just shows a white screen.
I've tried to reproduce the issue on some of my own devices (iPad mini 2 iOS 9, iPhone 5 iOS 9) but it works flawlessly, and it is working on some other customer's iOS devices.
I've tried removing the shortcut & creating it again, but it doesn't help.
I've added Sentry to my app to report me errors & bugs, and it works good for other bugs, but it's not reporting anything regarding this issue.
I don't know whether it is related or not, but I'm using cache busting technique: I add a hash to my JS & CSS files, set their `expires` attribute to `max` in NGINX, and I disable caching for `index.html` file.
Also, I should note that I can't connect my customers devices to a Mac to use Safari inspector.
How can I gather more info about what is happening and what is root of bug?
Thank you.